# How to reuse web.config transforms across multiple publish profiles?

Tags: asp.net

Given a set of code that needs to behave slightly differently on varying production servers, you can create release configurations in asp.net with different symbols so that the compiler can compile the code under each release configuration in the desired manner. However, the web.config file for each of these production deployments might need to be identical or nearly identical. Even so, web.config will vary as you deploy to dev/QA/staging servers, which is why we have the feature of having a transforms based on combinations of publication profile (often used to distinguish between dev/QA/prod deployments) and release configuration.

How can I set up using the same base transform for all of my production publication profiles when I need multiple production publication profiles? In my above example, I need multiple production publication profiles because I need to deploy with different symbols for the compiler even though web.config might be identical or very similar. If I don't reuse, I end up with duplication of the production publication profile transforms across each of the different release configurations.

For example, suppose I am setting up a website to work differently if accessed within a network vs called from outside the network, and I'll use two separate web servers for that variance in the deployment of the website. Where before I had release configurations Debug and Release, I now have additionally Internal Debug and Internal Release. I have four release configuration transforms (Web.Debug.config, Web.Internal Debug.config, ...). For publication profiles, I have ProductionExternal and ProductionInternal. Everything up to this point seems ok. However, then I also have to create Web.ProductionExternal.config and Web.ProductionInternal.config which set up connections to databases and the like that are identical or perhaps nearly identical. I'd prefer to instead be able to say inside Web.ProductionInternal.config to use everything in Web.ProductionExternal.config plus XYZ modifications so that as I need to update, I only have one place to update.

This problem gets worse as you look across dev/QA deployments, or if there are more publication profiles that are similar.

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/553960/Chainedplus-2fplusNestedplusWeb-configplusTransfor appears to be describing the same problem I'm facing, but never got an answer.

Comment: I worked-around this by using a pre-build action in my csproj to duplicate the XDT file for each publish-profile - not ideal, but works.